# How do I fully install Ubuntu on a USB Flash Drive?

Tags: usb, system-installation

I need to Install Ubuntu on a Flash Drive because I don't have enough space on my Laptop to Dual-Boot. I need to Fully Install Ubuntu on a flash drive.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but it will be damn slow. Better make a live USB drive with space reserved to save your settings. Every Ubuntu distro can do that through `usb-creator-gtk`.

If you choose full install instead than plug your USB stick in, and start a normal install. When reaching the HDD selection, select your USB stick, and go forward.